# Custom names for pytest parametrized tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I've got a *pytest* test that's parametrized with a `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator using a custom function `load_test_cases()` that loads the test cases from a yaml file.

```py
class SelectTestCase:
    def __init__(self, test_case):
        self.select = test_case['select']
        self.expect = test_case['expect']

    def __str__(self):        # also tried __repr__()
        # Attempt to print the 'select' attribute in "pytest -v" output
        return self.select


def load_test_cases(path):
    with open(path, "rt") as f:
        test_cases = yaml.safe_load_all(f)
        return [ SelectTestCase(test_case) for test_case in test_cases ]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_case", load_test_cases("tests/select-test-cases.yaml"))
def test_select_prefixes(test_case):
    # .. run the test
```

It works well except that the tests when run with `pytest -v` are displayed with `test_case0`, `test_case1`, etc parameters.

```
tests/test_resolver.py::test_select_prefixes[test_case0] PASSED  [ 40%]
tests/test_resolver.py::test_select_prefixes[test_case1] PASSED  [ 60%]
tests/test_resolver.py::test_select_prefixes[test_case2] PASSED  [ 80%]
tests/test_resolver.py::test_select_prefixes[test_case3] PASSED  [100%]
```

I would *love* to see the `select` attribute displayed instead, e.g.

```
tests/test_resolver.py::test_select_prefixes["some query"] PASSED  [ 40%]
tests/test_resolver.py::test_select_prefixes["another query"] PASSED  [ 60%]
```

I tried to add `__str__()` and `__repr__()` methods to the *SelectTestCase* class but it didn't make any difference.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define how your parametrized test names look using the [ids parameter](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids). This can be a list of strings, or a function that takes the current parameter as argument and returns the ID to be shown in the test name.

So, in your case it is sufficient to use `str` as that function, as you have already implemented `__str__` for the parameters (which are of type `SelectTestCase`). If you just write:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_case", load_test_cases("tests/select-test-cases.yaml"),
                         ids=str)
def test_select_prefixes(test_case):
    # .. run the test
```

you will get the desired behavior, e.g.

```
tests/test_resolver.py::test_select_prefixes[some query] PASSED  [ 40%]
tests/test_resolver.py::test_select_prefixes[another query] PASSED  [ 60%]
```

apart from the apostrophes (which you can add by adapting `__str__` accordingly).